# Powershell Excel - Save file with Encoding as Unicode UTF-8

Tags: excel, csv, powershell, utf-8

I have the below Powershell script which works great to convert excel files to csv. I am running into one final problem, when running this over special characters, these are being lost or replaced. To solve this I would like to save the files encoded using UTF-8 when saving to csv.

After reading the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=vs.120).aspx) I believe I need to change a parameter in the .SaveAs clause to encode the file, however I couldn't find an example with this working.

What is the correct parameter to add in order to allow the csv files to be saved with the desired encoding?

```
$InputDirectory = 'Files are here'
$OutputDirectory = 'Files go here'

#Function to change excel files to csv

Function ExcelCSV ($File)
{
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
    {
        $ws.SaveAs(("{0}{1}" -f $OuputDirectory,$Files.Name -replace ‘.xlsx$’,"") + ".csv", 6)
    }
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()

    }


#Looping through files, checking their extensions, converting excel to csv.

foreach ($Files in (Get-ChildItem -Path $InputDirectory))
    {

    $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Files)

    if ($extn -eq ".xlsx")

    {
    ExcelCSV($Files)
    }

    Elseif ($extn -eq ".xls")

    {
    ExcelCSV($Files)
    }

    Else
    {
    Copy-Item ("{0}{1}" -f $InputDirectory,$Files.Name) ("{0}{1}" -f $OuputDirectory,$Files.Name)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in Excel without some workarounds. Here is the one I created when I faced that problem:

[Export-ExcelCSV.ps1](https://gist.github.com/majkinetor/bda75f4ca7b30fb6cd444a46425b319d)

Here, each sheet is converted to CSV.

This solution exports as UnicodeText. CRLFs can pass on next line but are inside `"` (this might be a problem for some CSV readers). The only small problem is that it kills or running Excels and I didn't find a way around it.

Comment: I just gave you a working solution in several lines of code that produces valid CSV files.Your attitude is exaggerated IMO and has nothing to do with powershell per se. Anyway, could you share what python code you used ?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with `powershell` if you wanted `python`?

Comment: @gravity I wanted a solution to convert the files. I saw powershell as a good possible solution. Upon trialing this I realised it couldn't be done in a quick/easy/sensible way and required workarounds such as the one proposed above. Powershell would have worked great if it could have done this easily using the .SaveAs function, but alas it could not.

Comment: @Tminer, this is not powrshell stuff but Excel thing - seems that Excel does't implement correctly this functionality or at least it is not intuitive. Folks from `pandas` could implement any kind of logic to fix that. In order to use your solution on arbitrary system you have to install at least 3 things - python, gem and pandas. Those things may need extra configuration in enterprise environment (like proxy server) and since Python culture on Windows is not that strong, engineers usually don't know such stuff by default. Powershell on the other hand will work everywhere without any setup.

Comment: @Tminer, plus, not to mention number of other potential problems like python/library collisions, network problems etc. Powershell is simply the right tool for the job in this case and the most resilient option.

Answer (score 4):

6 is the format value to save as CSV ANSI - change it to 62 to save as CSV UTF-8.

Full list of formats & values here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat