# X++ SysExcelWorkbook.saveAs - change encoding

Tags: excel, csv, com, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to convert XLS to CSV using job in AX2012. I have some non-ASCII characters in my XLS and I need to find out how can I set SysExcelWorkbook.saveAs method to use specific encoding (eg. UTF-8).

```
static void ExcelToCsv(Args _args)
{
    SysExcelApplication application;
    SysExcelWorkbooks   workbooks;
    SysExcelWorkbook    workbook;
    FileName            xlsFile, csvFile;
    ;

    application = SysExcelApplication::construct();
    application.displayAlerts(false);
    workbooks = application.workbooks();

    xlsFile = @"C:\test.xlsx";
    csvFile = @"C:\result.csv";

    workbooks.open(xlsFile);
    workbook = workbooks.item(1);

    workbook.saveAs(csvFile, 6);
    // workbook.saveAs(resFile, 22);
    // workbook.saveAs(resFile, 23);
    // workbook.saveAs(resFile, 24);
    application.quit();
}
```

The code above generates CSV, but all non-ASCII characters are not displaying property when opening in text editor. I expect that I will be able to choose encoding for my CSV file programmatically or use source (XSL) encoding. Is there a way to achieve this with X++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without some workarounds as it appears to be an Excel limitation. It's do-able though if you really need it.

It uses the Excel COM object to do the work, and you can see the reference here, where I can't find any options to specify encoding:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

[Here is the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215526/powershell-excel-save-file-with-encoding-as-unicode-utf-8), albeit in `Powershell` instead of `X++` with solution (I think) being to export to `UnicodeText` instead of `CSV`, then replacing `\t` with `,` in the output file.

It looks like you could output to `UnicodeText` by making the below change to your code, then you could just use some other string-replace to update the final file.

```
#Excel
// workbook.saveAs(csvFile, 6); // 6 == #xlCSV
workbook.saveAs(csvFile, #xlUnicodeText);
```

I'm not sure if this truly fixes your encoding issue without testing. I'd also want to double-check how single/double quotes are handled.